# Parse XML file to check 2 child nodes before returning a 3rd node to datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xpath

I am using ASP.net coding in C#.  I am trying to read in an XML file and then check two of the child nodes to ensure they meet criteria.  If so then I am trying to return the text of the other child nodes belonging to the same parent.

Sample XML:

```
<JobList>
    <Job>
        <JobTitle>Job 1</JobTitle>
        <ReqId>1234</ReqId>
        <filter1>
            <label>location</label>
            <value>texas</value>
        </filter1>
        <filter2>
            <label>type</label>
            <value>admin</value>
        </filter2>
    </Job>
</JobList>
```

I want the datalist to show the JobTitle and the ReqId when the filter1/value = texas and the filter2/value = admin.  I am able to write a list of the locations with the code below but I can't determine how to select on 2 conditions and then use the parent of that match to get a different child to give to the datalist.  Here is my latest version:

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;   
String xmlpath = "test.xml";      
docNav = new XPathDocument(xmlpath);
nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
NodeIter = nav.Select("/JobList/Job/filter1/value[contains(.,'texas')]");
StreamWriter stw = File.AppendText("C:\\test.txt");
while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
{
    NodeIter.Current.MoveToParent();
    //NodeIter.Current.MoveToParent();
    NodeIter.Current.MoveToChild("JobTitle",xmlpath);
    stw.WriteLine("Job Title: {0}", NodeIter.Current.Value);
 };
 stw.Close();
```

I have tried this and it does not work:

```
NodeIter = nav.Select("(/Job-Listing/Job/filter1/value[contains(.,'texas')]) and (/Job-Listing/Job/filter3/value[contains(.,'admin')])");
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch that old xml parser

Use LINQ2XML. It's simple and cool

```
XElement doc=XElement.Load("yourXml.xml");

var lst=doc.Elements("Job")
                 .Where(x=>x.Element("filter1").Element("value").Value=="texas" &&
                          x.Element("filter2").Element("value").Value=="admin")
                 .Select(y=>
                            new
                            {
                               title=y.Element("JobTitle").Value,
                                id=y.Element("ReqId").Value
                            })
                 .ToList();
```

Now you can iterate over lst

```
foreach(var l in lst)
{
    l.title;
    l.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried implementing Linq and your code is giving me this error on the where line:   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new objects expressions can be used as a statement.

Comment: Why not simply change `Descendants().Elements("Job")` to `Elements("Job")`

Comment: Also this won't work as is, because the where's x is the new object from the Select.  Move the Where above the Select statement to have access to the Job Element. (fixed the code myself)

Comment: This is working after I changed this part:  `.Where(=>x.Element`   to  `.Where(x=>x.Element`  thanks for your assistance